# Declaring the source files in a separate folder in Makefile

Tags: makefile

My makefile has the following section:

```
SRCS   = src/main.c src/sdlshape.c src/sdlevent.c
OBJS   = bin/main.o bin/sdlshape.o bin/sdlevent.o
```

Is there a way I could use a separate variable to substitute the `src/` and `bin/` folders in these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for, but maybe you can do something like this

```
SRC    = src
SRCS   = $(SRC)/main.c $(SRC)/sdlshape.c $(SRC)/sdlevent.c
```

another approach is to use `$(wildcard ... )`.

If you are looking for a sample of `Makefile` where you have different folders for includes, objects, etc., take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/fortran-and-gnu-make/

I know it's Fortran based, but you can still get the feeling of how to structure it.

Comment: And/or `OBJS := $(patsubst src/%.c,bin/%.o,$(SRCS))`

Comment: The approach with `$(wildcard ...)` was more suited to my scenario, but according to my question, the first approach was [more] correct. Thank you! for the help.